# I want to find a fast path.(AStar Algorithm)

Tags: a-star

there is my astar algorithm

```
    while (!find || open.Count > 0)
    {
        Vector2 current = LowestF(Start, open, Destination);

        if (current == Destination)
        {
            find = true;
            break;
        }

        close.Add(current);
        open.Remove(current);

        List<Vector2> adjacent = MoveDirection(current);

        lowF = int.MaxValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < adjacent.Count; i++)
        {
            if (close.Contains(adjacent[i]))
                continue;

            if(getF(Start, adjacent[i], Destination) < lowF)
            {
                lowF = getF(Start, adjacent[i], Destination);
                lowV = adjacent[i];
            }

            if (!open.Contains(adjacent[i]))
            {
                open.Add(adjacent[i]);
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.0125f);
        }
    }
```

But I can't get a fast track. What should I do to get a quick route?
If a node is required, the Node has Parent and Pos.

- I want a simple code.

result
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQLP1.png)

Comment: Same answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565789/astar-parent-getpath